# Closed form for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{O_{n}^{(p)}}{(2n-1)^{q}}$, with $O_{n}^{(s)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k-1)^{s}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta, euler-sums

Consider the sum

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{O_{n}^{(p)}}{(2n-1)^{q}}\text{, with }O_{n}^{(s)}=1+\frac{1}{3^{s}}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{s}}$$

My question is: if there exists some general theorems that allow to represent this sums in terms of the Riemann Zeta function, like Borwein-Borwein-Girgensohn theorem for Euler sums?

Comment: These Euler sums are well-known to be solvable (in terms of $\zeta$) for $p+q\leq 5$ and in other cases (like $p=q$), see [The Bible](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure, which theorem exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm most interested in the case $p=2n,$ $q=2n+1$.

Comment: They belong to quadratic Euler sums. Flajolet and Salvy's paper (the link) does **not** solve the problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your notation a bit
and playing around.

If
$O_{n}(s)
=1+\frac{1}{3^{s}}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{s}}
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{(2k-1)^s}
$,
$O(s)
=O_{\infty}(s)
$,
and
$s(p, q)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{O_{n}(p)}{(2n-1)^{q}}
$
then

$s(p, q)+s(q, p)
=O(p)O(q)+O(p+q)
$.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
s(p, q)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{O_{n}(p)}{(2n-1)^{q}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{(2k-1)^p}}{(2n-1)^{q}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^{q}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^{q}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^{q}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^{q}}-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^{q}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\left(O(q)-O_{k-1}(q)\right)\\
&=O(p)O(q)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}O_{k-1}(q)\\
&=O(p)O(q)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}(O_{k}(q)-\frac1{(2k-1)^q})\\
&=O(p)O(q)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}O_{k}(q)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^p}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^q}\\
&=O(p)O(q)-s(q, p)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2k-1)^{p+q}}\\
&=O(p)O(q)-s(q, p)+O(p+q)
\\
\end{array}
$

Some additional 
definitions and stuff
which might be useful.

$Z_{n}(s)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^s}
$

$E_{n}(s)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{(2k)^s}
=\frac1{2^s}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^s}
=\frac1{2^s}Z_{n}(s)
$

$O_{n}(s)+E_{n}(s)
=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac1{k^s}
=Z_{2n}(s)
$
so
$O_{n}(s)
=Z_{2n}(s)-E_{n}(s)
=Z_{2n}(s)-\frac1{2^s}Z_{n}(s)
$

$O(s)
=O_{\infty}(s)
$,
$E(s)
=E_{\infty}(s)
$,
$Z(s)
=\zeta(s)
=Z_{\infty}(s)
$.

$O(s)
=Z(s)-E(s)
=Z(s)-\frac1{2^s}Z(s)
=(1-2^{-s})Z(s)
$

Comment: What about $p+q$ being odd?

Comment: I don't see where my answer depends on the parity of p or q.

Comment: I was thinking about the general case $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{O_{n}^{(p)}}{(2n-1)^{q}}$

Comment: Don't know about that. I was doing my usual playing around and found, to my surprise, the expression with p and q exchanged. So if you know s(p, q), you can get s(q, p).